# Solving integral for x in MATLAB, where x is bound and part of the integrand

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration, equation-solving

I am trying to solve an equation for x in Matlab, but keep getting the error:

> Empty sym: 0-by-1

The equation has an integral, where x is the upper bound and also part of the integrand [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyecJ.png). The code I use is the following:

```
a = 0.2; b= 10; c = -10; d = 15; mu = 3; sig = 1;
syms x t
eqn = 0 == a + b*normcdf(x,mu,sig)+c*int( normcdf(d + x - t,mu,sig)*normpdf(t,mu,sig),t,0,x);
A = vpasolve(eqn,x)
```

Any hints on where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the symbolic toolbox may not be good enough to solve that integral... Maybe some `assume` or some other trick can do the job, I personally could not find the way.

However, to test if this is solvable, I tried [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+t+normalcdf(d+%2B+x+-+t)*normalpdf(t)). It gives a result, that you can use.

```
eq1=a + b*normcdf(x,mu,sig);
resint=c*(t^3*(d - t + x)*erfc((mu - x)/(sqrt(2)*sig)))/(4*sig*exp((-mu + x)^2/(2*sig^2))*sqrt(2*pi));
A=vpasolve(eq1+subs(resint,t,x)-subs(resint,t,0) ==0)
```

gives `1.285643225712432599485355373093` in my PC.